# Get JSON result inside an OBJECT using Kotlin and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to GET an JSON result but it's inside an JSON Object. I search but only found responses in Java.
Someone can help me to GET the "from, to and amount" inside the request{}?
[HERE's THE API RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D99Jj.png)

My GET code:

```
@GET("convert")
fun getCurrencyConverter(
    @Query("from") from: String,
    @Query("to") to: String,
    @Query("amount") amount: String
): Call<ConvertModel>
```

My ConvertModel:

```
data class ConvertModel (
    @SerializedName("from")
    val from: String,
    @SerializedName("to")
    val to: String,
    @SerializedName("amount")
    val amountToConvert: Double,
    @SerializedName("result")
    val convertedAmount: Double
    )
```

That's what i need:

[API Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nubui.png)

## I SOLVED IT!!!!

The JSON "request" is an object.
So, i created the object as a data class and insert into.
Here's the code:

The "request" object:

```
    data class RequestModel(
        @SerializedName("from")
        val from: String,
        @SerializedName("to")
        val to: String,
        @SerializedName("amount")
        val amount: Double
    )
```

The "response" from API:

```
data class ConvertModelReserve (
    @SerializedName("request")
    val request: RequestModel,
    @SerializedName("result")
    val result: Double
    )
```

The Retrofit GET method:

```
@GET("convert")
    fun getCurrencyConverter(
        @Query("from") from: String,
        @Query("to") to: String,
        @Query("amount") amount: String
    ): Call<ConvertModelReserve>
```

Comment: If i get the question right - you can use interceptors https://medium.com/swlh/okhttp-interceptors-with-retrofit-2dcc322cc3f3

Comment: I already use interceptor. I just need to parse the JSON

Comment: Try using Gson library https://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library

Comment: I tried another think and works. Horewer thanks so much